# How to Configure SQL Server 2008 R2 Log Shipping

Tags: sql-server, configuration, database, sql-server-2008-r2, log-shipping

I need to set up a standby server using SQL Server Log Shipping. This is my first time doing this, so I'm following the instructions in the SQL Help step by step. Of course, I ran into a problem at the first step. The help file says:

> 1. Right click the database you want to use as your primary database in the log shipping configuration, and then click Properties.
> 2. Under Select a page, click Transaction Log Shipping.

I do not see a menu entry for Transaction Log Shipping. Here's what I see:
[image: Database Properties]

So why am I not being offered this option?

Answer (score 3):

In order to see the "Transaction Log Shipping" option in SQL Server Management Studio, you have to have the complete management tools option select. Try to re-install management studio, and check the box for "Management Tools - Basic" and the box for "Management Tools - Complete"

[image]

Also, you can't log ship a database that has an ID of 1 - 4 since SQL Server assumes that it's either `master`, `model`, `msdb` or `tempDB`.

Comment: Thanks, that's all good information. I presume this 'complete install' has to be on the management station (which is remote)?

Comment: Yes, it has to be on whichever machine you are trying to enable log shipping on the server from. Not the server itself.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the advice. Of course, I don't have the installation media handy so will need to download a fresh copy tomorrow.